# fastest way to get a property by name if it exists anywhere in the object graph

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to be able to retrieve the value of a property if it exists anywhere within the object graph and I would like to know if there is a faster way to the option I have come up with below.

I have specifically opted for tree traversal instead of recursion, because it uses less stack frames and memory and because traversal is faster.

example:

```
const obj= {someObj:{}, someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: {featureRole: "canary"}}}
const prop= findProperties(obj, "featureRole");
console.log(prop); //canary
```

- breadth first search properties

```
findProperty(obj: Record<string, any>, propId: string): any {
    if (obj && obj[propId] != undefined) {
      return obj[propId];
    }
    const props = [obj];
    while (props.length) {
      const prop = props.shift();
      if (typeof prop === 'object') {
        if (prop && prop[propId] != undefined) {
          return prop[propId];
        }
        for (const innerProp in prop) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(prop, innerProp) && typeof prop[innerProp] === 'object') {
            props.push(prop[innerProp]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this recursively, either returning as soon as a value is found:

```js
const obj = {
  someObj: {}, someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: { featureRole: "canary" } },
  obj: { someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: { featureRole: "cockatoo" } } }
}

const findProperties = (obj, prop) => {
  if (obj[prop] !== undefined) {
    return obj[prop];
  }
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      const res = findProperties(obj[key], prop);
      if (res !== null) {
        return res
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

const prop = findProperties(obj, "featureRole");
console.log(prop); //canary
```

Or collecting all the possible matches:

```js
const obj = {
  someObj: {}, someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: { featureRole: "canary" } },
  obj: { someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: { featureRole: "cockatoo" } } }
}

const findProperties = (obj, prop, res = []) => {
  if (obj[prop] !== undefined) {
    res.push(obj[prop]);
  }
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      findProperties(obj[key], prop, res);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

const prop = findProperties(obj, "featureRole");
console.log(prop); // ["canary", "cockatoo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with some restrictions like `\"` in property name/value:

```
findProperties = (o, prop) => JSON.stringify(o).match(new RegExp(`"\(${prop}\)":"\([^"]*\)"`, 'gi')).map(m => m.split(':').map(str => str.replace(/"/gi, '')));
```

Usage:

```
findProperties(obj, "featureRole").map(([,v]) => console.log(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursivity to search in your object.

```js
const object = {
  a: {
   d: 24
  },
  b: {
    e: 5,
    f: {
        g: 'B'
    }
  },
  c: 12
};

function getProp(object, propName) {
  if (propName in object) {
    return object[propName];
  } else {
    for (const prop in object) {
      if (typeof object[prop] === 'object') {
        const results = getProp(object[prop], propName);
        if(!!results) {
          return results;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can play with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/tpbhexgw/10/

Comment: This fails on the OP's input, and more generally if the passed 'prop' is not within the top level object, or nested within the value of the first property.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, forgot to check if result of search in each branch has result or not to not return null of the first failed ! Response updated, but it's the same code than your. :) Glad to see we've come to the same result. Your method that find all occurence is a good way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

This library is build from the ground up for speed. It uses iteration instead of recursion internally.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const obj = { someObj: {}, otherObj: { some: { deep: { nested: { key: {} } } } }, someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: { featureRole: 'canary' } } };

// compile search function (only needs to be done once)
const searchFn = objectScan(['**.featureRole'], { abort: true, rtn: 'bool' });

// execute search
console.log(searchFn(obj));
// => true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

While this will not be faster than writing your own iterative solution, it has the major advantage that it will prune the search tree if you have any other meta information about the key position.

For example if you knew that the key is at exactly one or two nestings deep, you could write the following and it would never search deeper than that

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const obj = { someObj: {}, otherObj: { some: { deep: { nested: { key: {} } } } }, someOtherObj: { nestedObjet: { featureRole: 'canary' } } };

const searchFn = objectScan(['{*,*.*}.featureRole'], { abort: true, rtn: 'bool' });

console.log(searchFn(obj));
// => true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

These kind of changes have typically a much greater impact than micro-optimizing code (that a different compiler might do who knows what with anyways).